# How to display column using thousand seperator in Select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have integer column in my table which contains some values.
I want to use select statement and show these values as thousand seperator.

Can you please show me how this select statement will look like?

Comment: This http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html or this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-functions.html didn't provide an answer?

Comment: Please give an example of what you want.

Comment: You want MySQL *and* SQL Server answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`FORMAT(X,D)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(12345.6789, 0); -- outputs '12,345'  
SELECT FORMAT(12345.6789, 2); -- outputs '12,345.68'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function.